# Removing rows from the dataframe 1 where equivalent row in dataframe2 has null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames and I am using the last columns from both the data frames to calculate classification metrics.

I want to make sure the values are correct, one of my data-frames is being loaded from database and there are chances that I might get NaN values in that data frame.

I want to delete the row which consist of NaN values from both the data frames, my other dataframe won't have any NaN but I want to check NaN values in first data frame and delete the equivalent row from first and second data frame so that my classification happens only on real values.

I am not sure how to achieve this

[image: 2 Datagframes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) along with [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to create a boolean mask, then you can filter the dataframes using this mask:

```
m = df2.isna().any(axis=1) # boolean mask representing rows in df2 having nan values
df1 = df1[~m]
df2 = df2[~m]
```

This results:

```
# print(df1)
   product_id   style   label   store
0         100  style0  label0  store0
1         101  style1  label1  store1
3         103  style3  label3  store3

# print(df2)
   product_id   style   label   store
0         100  style0  label0  store0
1         101  style1  label1  store1
3         103  style3  label3  store3
```

Comment: So this deletes the row from both the data-frames if any one of the rows consists None/Null/Nan values?

Comment: @AshishAhuja yep.

Comment: This solution just deletes the rows consisting of None values, which is what I asked for. Can we get to know what all rows were deleted? I may need to investigate it further as to why Null values were introduced.

Comment: Yes, you can just use `deleted_rows = df2[m]` after this line `m = df2.isna().any(axis=1) `.

Comment: Hi @AshishAhuja Lets continue the discussion [HERE](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218789/ds3).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of approaching this problem, the way I would get to it is by first getting all the index of the null values in the df1 and than find that index in df2 and remove it:

```
   rows_with_nans = [index for index, row in df1.iterrows() if row.isnull().any()]
   print(rows_with_nans)
```

And in order to delete from df2 I would do this :

```
  df2.drop(rows_with_nans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df_database.isna()
df_database.drop(mask, axis=0, inplace=True)
df_non_databse.drop(mask, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26178561)